# iphone download image with variable using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, image, download, asihttprequest

I got stuck something annoying.

I uploaded images to server it's ok. 
However, when i try to download image from server i want to get image with string variable. here is my php code server side

```
         ....

        echo "image_getting;";
        $fullPath = $_POST['download_image'];
        echo file_get_contents($fullPath);

         ....
```

if i remove first line from my server [request responseData] working correctly.
However, i want to also get "image_getting;" because i am also downloading some different types.

if i can clear, iphone side
when i say

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);

    NSArray *resultResponseArray = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    if([[resultResponseArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"image_getting"])
    {
          NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
          UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:aData];
          .......
    }
    else if...
....
}
```

as you can see above response data also taking echo "image_getting" how do i split it.
I tried to convert and split them it didn't work.

I should say, i am very bad with php.

I will be appreciated, if someone help me.
Thanks

EDIT:Solution Php side

```
    header('X-Return: image_getting;');
    $fullPath = $_POST['download_image'];
    echo file_get_contents($fullPath);
```

iphone side

```
    NSLog(@"header %@",[[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"X-Return"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put the "image_getting" into a HTTP header in the response instead? That would make the parsing much easier - you can then retrieve the header:

```
NSString *whatever = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"X-Whatever"];
```

and then [request responseData] will only contain the image.

Comment: Actually i found a way that i know "image_gettin;" is 14 bytes and i can split it but it was not the way i will use. Your way is much more usable, thank you very much.