# ASIHTTPRequest for dummies

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I'm a COMPLETE DUMMY in ASIHTTPRequest. I have just downloaded the library and added it to my project and now i'm trying to understand basics of working with it. I've found some pretty good example [**here**](http://iphone-example.blogspot.com/p/asihttprequest-example.html)

this little tutorial is about uploading images to a server. I tried it and things seem to work (but i'm confused with NSString returned by [request responseString], it returned HTML code of a whole web page ) but i would like to know how to download images (or anything uploaded) back from the server. After searching a bit i found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160534/iphone-download-image-with-variable-using-asihttprequest) and it gave me no answers but more questions only, cause it's quite unclear for me. 
Let me enumurate my questions:

1) Could you please provide me with a little piece of code showing how to download data (no matter what kind of data: images,strings,numbers etc) from a server?

2)Should i know php code of the server side in order to work with a server?

3)If yes - how do i know php code of the server side?

4)How important is it if a request is proccessed by a php script or by any different means?

5)What is the role of responseString? Is it ok that it returned me a huge HTML code?

6)The main question. Is there a good tutorial for ASIHTTPRequest? Something like "ASIHTTPRequest for dummies"? I found official documentation [**here**](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) but it explains the stuff really poorly and i just can't find any other tutorials.

Any help is desperately needed.

Comment: note: don't learn ASI anymore :) It is a dead horse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) Could you please provide me with a little piece of code showing how to download data (no matter what kind of data: images,strings,numbers etc) from a server?

here you can find a very basic POST example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/webroot/index.php/test/signUp"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addPostValue:@"Raul" forKey:@"name"];
[request addPostValue:@"Hello World" forKey:@"message"];

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

it uses blocks, so that wverything is nicely packed together in one function and you don't have to deal with delegates and the rest. ([source](http://labs.grupow.com/index.php/2011/03/using-asihttprequest/))

If you just want to GET a page, you can use:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

[request startAsynchronous];

> 2)Should i know php code of the server side in order to work with a server?

absolutely not necessary.

> 3)If yes - how do i know php code of the server side?

N.A.

> 4)How important is it if a request is proccessed by a php script or by any different means?

the language the server is written in is not relevant either.

> 5)What is the role of responseString? Is it ok that it returned me a huge HTML code?

responseString contains all the data that the server sent back to you as an NSString. It can be huge...

> 6)The main question. Is there a good tutorial for ASIHTTPRequest? Something like "ASIHTTPRequest for dummies"? I found official documentation here click but it explains the stuff really poorly and i just can't find any other tutorials.

I don't know of a tutorial "for dummies" like you say; you should try and follow the docs on the site; they may appear complex, but are not really.

On another note, you probably already know it: [development of ASIHTTP has been ceased](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;). If you are just starting learning about it, you might better think of considering an alternative. Look at the linked page for some alternatives.

Comment: did you also copy the PHP file the author provided and installed it under you web server? what does the HTML you receive look like (at least partly)?

Comment: fine. I have also added another snippet of code for a GET request... hope it helps...