# Downloading images and songs from server URL

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app i would like to download images and songs from server url how can we achieve this through programmatically. Any one can suggest or help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

We are using it in our app to download profile images from Facebook and make HTTP/HTTPS json requests to the server. It can cache downloaded files on local cache speeding up retrieving the same files. It also supports gzip when you need to send lots of text to/from the phone.

Click [How to use it](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) tab for some examples of how to use it in your own app.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256926/asihttprequest-for-dummies) gives a basic POST example.

Another alternative is native iOS class [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but it doesn't have as many features as ASIHTTPRequest so choose depending on what you need.